# split string in php "genesis 1:3-16" to "genesis", "1", "3", "16"

Tags: php, regex, string, split

In php when user saves a text, I need to split string as

"genesis1:3-16" ==> "genesis", "1", "3", "16"

"revelation2:3-5" ==> "revelation", "2", "3", "5"

The conditions are there will be no white spaces between all characters I need to split according to symbol ":", "-", and character. the numbers can go up to only '999' 3 digits.

```
$sample = "genesis1:3-16";

//magic happens....

$book = "";        // genesis
$chapter = "";     // 1
$start_verse = ""; // 3
$end_verse = "";   //16
```

I have limited knowledge of reg expression and can't figure out using only strpos and substr...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please be sure to accept an answer or post questions when you return..http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex would accomplish what you are after:

```
([a-z]+)(\d{1,3}):(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})
```

Demo (with explanation of what each part does): https://regex101.com/r/uP4gW6/1

PHP Usage:

```
preg_match('~([a-z]+)(\d{1,3}):(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})~', 'genesis1:3-16', $data);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => genesis1:3-16
    [1] => genesis
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 16
)
```

With `preg_match` the `0` index is the found content. The subsequent indexes are each captured group.

If you have a fixed set of names the book could be you could replace `[a-z]+` with that list seperated by `|`, for example `revelation|genesis|othername`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = array();

preg_match('/^(.*?)\s*(\d+):(\d+)-(\d+)$/', $sample, $parts);

$book = $parts[1];

$chapter = $parts[2];

$startVerse = $parts[3];

$endVerse = $parts[4];
```

Comment: You need to take into account the specs provided by OP. `the numbers can go up to only '999'` and `there will be no white spaces between all characters`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this simple pattern

```
([a-zA-Z]+|\d{1,3})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iY4vE7/5)